# Django group by annotate Min

Tags: django, django-models

I got two models :

models.py

```
class Representation(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)

class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

and then I'd like to have the next 5 incoming shows, and the best i can do is a clever hack like that, but this just uses a ton of queries, and I'm sure there is a more pythonic way to do it

```
i=5
list_shows = set()
while (len(list_shows) < 5:
    for rep in Representation.objects.filter(datetime__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('-datetime')[:i]:
        list_shows.add(rep.show)
    i+=1
    if i>100:
        break
```

I also tryed something like this :

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models import Min
Show.objects.annotate(date=Min('representation__datetime')).filter(date__gte=datetime.now()).order_by('date')[:5]
```

But this doesn't take the case where a show already played yesterday but play against tonight.

Comment: what is your query ? min of what?

Comment: @levi min of datetime, but datetime greater than equal now, and this over a reverse ForeignKey :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
Show.objects.filter(representation_set__datetime__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('representation_set__datetime')[:5]
```